# Simplistic ADT queue implementation using provided issue

Tags: c, queue, adt

```
/****************************************************************************/
/* File: queue.h
 */
/****************************************************************************/

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/*              Simple Queue ADT                                            */
/*                                                                          */
/*              Declaration                                                 */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    int key;
    int value;
} data_t;

typedef struct queueNode {
    struct queueNode *next, *prev;
    data_t *data;
} QueueNode;

typedef struct queueType {
    QueueNode *head;
    QueueNode *tail;
} Queue;
```

/********************************************************************

Alright, so above I have a file provided for me called Queue.h, this makes sense to me in some respect as it gives data_t a pair of values (value and key) and stores that in a QueueNode, which is placed in either the Tail or Head of a queue.

The problem I'm having is that I DO NOT KNOW how to use this to create a Class called Queue.c that does the following functions:

---

```
voidinitQueue(Queue *self){
}

void enQueue(Queue *self, data_t *data){
}

QueueNode *frontNode(Queue *self){
}

data_t *frontValue(Queue *self){
}

data_t *dequeue(Queue *self){
}

void removeNode(queue *self, queueNode *p){
}

QueueNode *findNode(queue *self, data_t *data){
}

void printQ(queue *self, char *label){
}
```

---

With this (not meant to be altered) main():

```
/*
int main ()
{
    Queue myQueue;
    QueueNode *p;
    data_t data[10], d2;
    int i;

    initQueue (&myQueue);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        data[i].key = i;
        data[i].value = 10*i;

        enQueue (&myQueue, &data[i]);
    }

    printQ (&myQueue, "MyQueue:" );

}
*/
```

---

Now I'm not going to ask anyone to do this for me, that doesn't help me at all in the long run, but I have absolutely no idea what to do.

I have a basic understanding of how a queue works, my problem is how to execute it. I'm also learning java in another class right now and it's begun to confuse me what rule apply to what class (as in school class, not java class)

If someone could walk me through how one's meant to work with a few of these (or at least initQueue) I'd be really grateful, Ive been working on this for 12 hours now and I'm getting desperate....

Edit: 
Update: This is what i have now:

```
void initQueue(Queue *self)
{
self->head = NULL;
self->tail = NULL;
}

void enQueue(Queue *self, data_t *data)
{
self->head = data;
}
```

Comment: It's not java it's C.

Comment: Beside that C (other than Java) doesn't know the concept of classes, what _exactly_ is your problem? Is it an algorithmic problem? Do you have trouble with the data structure, the syntax, ...? Hint: since you claim to know what a queue is, draw pictures that show what your code is imposed to do, and start coding afterwards.

Comment: I've seen picture of how a queue works: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-gentle-introduction-to-data-structures-how-queues-work-f8b871938e64         The problem lies with I don't know how to code in C at all. The only thing I've been taught properly to code in is Python, and the bare basics of Java.

Comment: I've gotten the queue initiated, as seen in the update at the bottom, but how I add things INTO that queue is fighting me tooth and nail. I've tried dozens of different ways of putting it in, but they all get rejected with errors, some of which make no sense. Like for instance, I keep getting "Expected ; before }"  error, implying I may have an extra ; or } problem, but I dont, I've checked it thouroughly. 2-3 {, 2-3}, ; at the end of lines that don't have {}s.

Comment: If you are new in C, a queue is probably not the best thing to start with. Pointers (as you need here) can be confusing for programmers who know languages as Java only.

Comment: Well tell that to my university who directed me to this class to take this assignment. ..... Is your advice here really for me to give up?

Comment: Is this really your first task in a C class? What are the class prerequisites?

Comment: CSC 242 Digital Logic and Computer Organization (Machine Language and Assembly)
CSC 231 Data Structures

Comment: After classes on data structures and assembler you should be able to understand queues as well as pointers. Thus: 1. understand the queue data structure (the both functions you provided do not suggest you did); 2. elaborate your algorithms (draw figures!); 3. write the code. If you have problems, describe exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Well this has been amazingly helpful..... I now have stated I do know how the structures work, I know how each function should act, but I do not know why nothing here works. The code I provided is only like the way it is because it produced the least amount of errors after running it. (that is the only way I could get initQueue with no errors).